# DataStax AMI installed in VPC hangs at Installation started

Tags: datastax-enterprise, datastax, amazon-ami, amazon-vpc

I experienced this issue today with ami-ada2b6c4 creating a new instance in a VPC without a public IP - logged in via SSH and the terminal hangs on Installation started.

I used Ctrl-C to interrupt and this printed on the terminal:

```
Installation started ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "datastax_ami/ds4_motd.py", line 239, in <module>
    run()
  File "datastax_ami/ds4_motd.py", line 228, in run
    waiting_for_status()
  File "datastax_ami/ds4_motd.py", line 100, in waiting_for_status
    time.sleep(5)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I followed a [link to github](https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI/issues/51) posted by joaquin for a similar problem and added an entry to /etc/hosts. Logged off the instance and then reconnected. this time, got a different error.

```
Raiding complete
Waiting for nodetool...
The cluster is now in it's finalization phase. This should only take a moment...

Note: You can also use CTRL+C to view the logs if desired:
    AMI log: ~/datastax_ami/ami.log
    Cassandra log: /var/log/cassandra/system.log


Note: Ownership information does not include topology; for complete information, specify a keyspace
Datacenter: Solr
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Owns   Host ID                               Token                                    Rack
UN  10.0.10.92  53 KB      100.0%  c010f1d3-3d74-4c2b-ae88-9e3fecfc447c  -9223372036854755808                     rack1

Opscenter: http://10.0.10.92:8888/
    Please wait 60 seconds if this is the cluster's first start...


Tools:
    Run: datastax_tools
Demos:
    Run: datastax_demos
Support:
    Run: datastax_support


------------------------------------
DataStax AMI for DataStax Enterprise
and DataStax Community
AMI version 2.5
DataStax Enterprise version 4.5.2-1

------------------------------------


These notices occurred during the startup of this instance:
[ERROR] 10/15/14-18:16:08 git pull:
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection timed out while accessing https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI.git/info/refs
```

The security group does allow access to the internet - I was able to sudo apt-get update, for example.

Comment: If you can email me your ~/datastax_ami/ami.log and your new /etc/hosts file at <myfirstname>@datastax.com I can take a look. Also, do please mention the /etc/hosts line you added/changed. Thanks!

Comment: I am hitting the same issue, any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of learnings from my experience. Joaquin from Datastax was very helpful with his suggestions.

1. I passed in userdata using the advanced config in AWS Management GUI -

   --clustername EIP_ami --totalnodes 3 --version enterprise --username some.guy_some.com  --password changeme --searchnodes 3

but didn't change the number of instances to 3 in the GUI so only one node was created. this may have contributed to the problem.

After interrupting the initial hanging installation -

2. added this entry to /etc/hosts:

   127.0.1.1 ip-10-0-1-234
3. added an elastic IP to the instance and rebooted

I got to the 2nd error:

```
These notices occurred during the startup of this instance:
[ERROR] 10/15/14-18:16:08 git pull:
error: Failed connect to github.com:443; Connection timed out while accessing https://github.com/riptano/ComboAMI.git/info/refs
```

4. When I got to a bash prompt, I tested the git pull manually per Joaquin's advice:

   ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-234:~/datastax_ami$ git pull
   Already up-to-date.
   per Joaquin:

> Yes, that error message will stick around for the life of the machine.
>   Perhaps the `git pull` issue was a fluke.

Nodetool status says the node is up and acting normally. So, the learning here is to ignore the errors - none of them seem to affect the creation or operation of the node.